# How to scale and rotate squares to fit inside each other in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, translation, scaling

Im trying to scale and rotate 10 squares to fit inside each other recursively at a rotation angle of 45 in OpenGl. my output should look like this.
[image]

my current code is this

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    

    scale = 1.0f;
    angle = 45.0f;
    for (int  i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        transformObject(scale -=0.156f, Z_AXIS, angle -= 45.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
        
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Ist the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the square gets smaller by the scale *1/sqrt(2)* with each iteration of the loop. The outer rectangle is not transformed. The outer rectangle is not transformed. Change the scale and angle at the end of the loop:

```cpp
scale = 1.0f;
angle = 0.0f;
for (int  i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    transformObject(scale, Z_AXIS, angle, glm::vec3(0.0f));
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
        
    scale = 1.0f/sqrt(2.0f);
    angle -= 45.0f;
}
```

Comment: @BigFungus05 So what should I do? This is obviously not a problem of the code in the answer. How do you use/convert the angle in the `transformObject` function?